# Codeigniter Routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm trying to write an application that takes a parameter from the url and supplies it to the index function in the default controller. Then decides what to load depending on this parameter either a default home page or a custom page.

```
$route['(eventguide/:any)'] = 'eventguide';
```

This code works but only if I have the controller in the url like so:

example.com/eventguide/(parameter)

I don't want to include the controller name. So i'm not exactly sure how to route this.

Ideally the url would look like example.com/(parameter), is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're almost there:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "eventguide/index/$1";
```

And in your index() method you fetch the parameter:

```
public function index($parameter = null){

}
```

`$parameter` will now contain anything caught by the `:any` shortcut, which should be equivalent to `(\w)+` IIRC

Since this is a catch-all route, be careful to put **any other custom route** you want **before** it, otherwise they will never be reached.
For ex., if you have a controller "admin", your route files should be;:

```
$route['admin'] = "admin";
$route['(:any)'] = "eventguide/index/$1";
```

Comment: I have another controller called admin, when I try to load this it just takes me to the index controller. How do I link to this controller now? eg example.com/admin

Comment: I have a problem with routing. I'm using CI version 2.1.3. I did this and It works on internet (server), but not on my local server now. :/